# Pandas: cannot import name compat

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I have some code, `preprocess_align.py` which runs perfectly on my PC but I get an `ImportError` when running it on a server. The `ImportError` supposedly comes when `pandas` is imported. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_features.py", line 12, in <module>
    import preprocess_align as prep
  File "/home/influenza/preprocess_align.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/influenza/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/home/influenza/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "/home/influenza/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "/home/influenza/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pandas import compat
ImportError: cannot import name compat
```

The Python version is `Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)` and I have already used `conda update pandas` to update the version to the latest.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't tell us your pandas version, for 0.25,0.24,0.23 as the doc says about pandas.compat

```
Warning

The pandas.core, pandas.compat, and pandas.util top-level modules are PRIVATE. Stable functionality in such modules is not guaranteed.
```

as in 0.23 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/api.html?highlight=compat

it seems that downgrade to 0.23 works for me.
you may use

```
 pip uninstall pandas
 pip install --upgrade pandas==0.23.0
```

and in 0.24
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/index.html

and in stable(Now 0.25)
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html?highlight=compat

Comment: I has the same issue and I solved it by reinstalling pandas. Since the OP has mentioned that he is using conda. for Uninstallation conda remove --force pandas. Installing it back again conda install -c anaconda pandas