# ImportError: cannot import name 'lzip'

Tags: python, pandas, lzip

A script I'm running is failing at one of my imports, and I can't figure out why.

The offending line of code is:

```
from pandas.compat import lzip
```

Error message: `ImportError: cannot import name 'lzip'`

This script is being run in a conda virtual environment, with dependencies installed through conda. Specific to this case, I have pandas and pandas-compat installed, also through conda, and running on Python3.6. (3.6 because 3.7 is incompatible with pandas-compat in an earlier attempt on a python3.7 env)

Help please, or point to where I may find the solution?

Not sure why lzip wouldn't be available, save for the warning at the top of the [pandas API reference docu](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html) (`Warning The pandas.core, pandas.compat, and pandas.util top-level modules are PRIVATE. Stable functionality in such modules is not guaranteed.`). The first solution on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833698/pandas-cannot-import-name-compat) didn't work for me.

Current pandas version: 0.25.3

Current pandas-compat: 0.1.1

Current python: 3.6.7

Comment: It's OK for me:

Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Pandas: 0.23.4